# Why is init(coder:) being called when I provide an init() function

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am using SpriteKit and I am loading a SceneKit file that contains a number of sprites with custom classes. The scene never actually loads though because it reaches the first custom class and throws the `fatalerror` from the `required init?(coder:)` initializer. The custom class implements an initializer though and I am having trouble pinning down why it is choosing that initializer over the one I provided.

Custom Class:

```
class Bat: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite {
  var initialSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44, height: 24)
  var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Enemies")
  var flyAnimation = SKAction()

  init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: initialSize)

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    createAnimations()
    self.run(flyAnimation)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

  func createAnimations() {
    let flyFrames: [SKTexture] = [textureAtlas.textureNamed("bat"),
                                  textureAtlas.textureNamed("bat-fly")]

    let flyAction = SKAction.animate(with: flyFrames, timePerFrame: 0.12)
    flyAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(flyAction)
  }

  func onTap() {}
}
```

And here is the code attempting to load the scene and then loop through the children and initialize them:

Encounter Manager:

```
class EncounterManager {
  // Store encounter file names
  let encounterNames: [String] = [
    "EncounterA"
  ]

  // Each encounter is a node, store an array
  var encounters: [SKNode] = []

  init() {
    // Loop through each encounter scene and create a node for the encounter
    for encounterFileName in encounterNames {
      let encounterNode = SKNode()

      // Load the scene file into a SKScene instance and loop through the children
      if let encounterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: encounterFileName) {
        for child in encounterScene.children {

          // Create a copy of the scene's child node to add to our encounter node
          // Copy the position, name, and then add to the encounter
          let copyOfNode = type(of: child).init()
          copyOfNode.position = child.position
          copyOfNode.name = child.name
          encounterNode.addChild(copyOfNode)
        }
      }

      // Add the populated encounter node to the array
      encounters.append(encounterNode)
    }
  }

  // This function will be called from the GameScene to add all the encounter nodes to the world node
  func addEncountersToScene(gameScene: SKNode) {
    var encounterPosY = 1000

    for encounterNode in encounters {
      // Spawn the encounters behind the action, with increasing height so they do not collide
      encounterNode.position = CGPoint(x: -2000, y: encounterPosY)
      gameScene.addChild(encounterNode)

      // Double Y pos for next encounter
      encounterPosY *= 2
    }
  }
}
```

What I have noticed using breakpoints though is that it never gets past loading the scene. It fails on the line `if let encounterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: encounterFileName)` and the error is the fatal error in the initializer from the Bat class.

Any help understanding why it picks one initializer over the other would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Martin! Lou's answer below also explains that, and I am going to accept that for other people who land here. Thank you for the quick & accurate response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
 if let encounterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: encounterFileName)
```

Which calls SKScene's `init(fileNamed:)` which loads a file and decodes it with SKScene's coder init. That init loads the file and decodes each element in it with the node's coder init.

If you want to load from a file, you need to implement the coder init.

Comment: Thanks Lou, I will accept this when it lets me. I am going to try setting it to a `convenience` initializer and just call my custom init method from within it and see if that fixes it. I was actually unaware that it was archived and then unarchiving it during load.

Comment: I would call super to unarchive the base properties.

Comment: Actually you were correct Lou, it helps when you actually load the encounter haha, but everything loaded perfectly in place with the `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` call